# MySQL Find number of New Customers added by a Client followed by a period inactivity

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database problem trying to find the number of Customers added by a Client. Then after a period of inactivity of adding customers (3 months or more) they added Customers again.

The tables I am looking at are

1. Customers table (cu.Id, cu.Client, cu.DateAdded)
2. The Clients table (cl.Id, cl.Name)
3. The Payments table (py.Client, py.Customer, py.PaymentDate)

Many thanks

```
SELECT
    LAST_DAY(py.DueDate) AS Report_Month,
    cl.Name,
    COUNT(cu.Id) AS Customers_Joined
FROM Payments py
LEFT JOIN Clients cl ON cl.Id = py.Client
LEFT JOIN Customers cu ON cu.Id = py.Customer
WHERE 
    MONTH(py.DueDate) = MONTH(cu.DateAdded) 
    AND YEAR(py.DueDate) = YEAR(cu.DateAdded)
GROUP BY cl.Name, LAST_DAY(py.Due)
ORDER BY cl.ClientPrefix
```

The logic of this query is to join the tables up and based on the Payments log to match the date a customer is added with the date their payment is due to find number of NEW customers per Client.

I want to see historical month on month values of the Customers added.

Then if they have 3 months of more of new customers added I want to be able to see the last time they added customers and their count and I want to see the following date with the count.

```
Client Name Customer Added  NumJoiners  DateNextAdd NewJoiners  Days Since
Client A    2023-07-31  10  2023-10-31  15  >90
Client B    2023-06-30  9   2023-08-10  12  >90
Client C    2023-08-10  8   2023-06-22  21  >90
```

If there is a simpler way to do it without involving the Payments table then I would appreciate the guidance on that too. Since cu.Client links to cl.Id. (The Payments table is huge)

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use the payments table at all given you have dateadded in customers. Sample data and expected outcome as text would help clarify. Also your code implies that you can have a payments table row where there is no customer and/or client (driving from payment with left joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the need for the `Payments` table in this query, but maybe I am misunderstanding your requirements.

This [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions) uses the [`LEAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) window function to retrieve the values for the next row in the partition, and then the outer query joins to `Clients` and checks the [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```sql
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT
        Client,
        DateAdded,
        COUNT(*) AS NumJoiners,
        IFNULL(LEAD(DateAdded) OVER w, CURDATE()) AS DateNextAdd,
        IFNULL(LEAD(COUNT(*)) OVER w, 0) AS NextNumJoiners
    FROM Customers
    GROUP BY Client, DateAdded
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY DateAdded)
)
SELECT
    cl.Name,
    t1.DateAdded AS CustomerAdded,
    t1.NumJoiners,
    t1.DateNextAdd,
    t1.NextNumJoiners,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t1.DateAdded, t1.DateNextAdd) AS DaysSince
FROM t1
JOIN Clients cl ON t1.Client = cl.Id
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t1.DateAdded, t1.DateNextAdd) > 90;
```

Comment: hi - this is amazing. could you point me towards any books that talk about these advanced functions

Comment: It's all (well, mostly) in the MySQL docs - [12.20 Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) and [13.2.20 WITH (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).